# Oxidation products of propylene glycol

Tags: organic-chemistry

Working in a building that uses propylene glycol (PG) as antifreeze in a hydroponic heating system.  With complaints of chemical odors in offices, I conducted air sampling for glycols, aldehydes, and PAHs.  No airborne glycol or PAHs were detected, but low levels of aldehydes; acetone, acetaldehyde, butyraldehyde and formaldehyde are present building wide.  Not a chemist, so question is, if there is a leak in a closed hydroponic heating system, does the PG oxidize to aldehydes when it encounters occupied air?

A thick bioslime was present on the interior surface of the mechanical room glycol tank.  I was told that when glycol is exposed to air, it generates nutrients for microbes.  The bioslime analyzed as Yeast, and some PG is generated by Yeast and carbohydrates - all news to me.

Comment: By "bioslime" you probably mean "biofilm". You will find a lot more articles about "biofilms" on the web